# OpenGL Multithreading slower than using a single thread

Tags: c, multithreading, opengl

I'm using Windows 7 and using VC++ 2010  and this is a 32 bit application

I am trying to get my renderer to work multithreaded but as it turns out I made it slower than without using multiple threads.

I want it to have the main thread adding rendering commands to a list, and a worker thread that does the rendering of these commands.

This all does happen, and it draws to the screen fine, but I get less fps when doing so...

I used the benchmark tool in Fraps to get this data:

Time is the time it was benchmarked for, in this case 30 seconds.

Min, max, avg are all FPS values.

With Multithreading:

```
    Frames, Time (ms), Min, Max, Avg
     28100,     30000, 861,1025, 936.667
```

Without multithreading:

```
Frames, Time (ms), Min, Max, Avg
 21483,     30000, 565, 755, 716.100
```

Here is some pseudocode (with the relevant event function calls):

```
Main Thread:
    Add render comands to queue
    ResetEvent (renderCompletedEvent);
    SetEvent (renderCommandsEvent);
    WaitForSingleObject (renderCompletedEvent, INFINITE);

Render Thread:
    WaitForSingleObject (renderCommandsEvent, INFINITE);
    Process commands
    SetEvent (renderCompletedEvent);
    ResetEvent (renderCommandsEvent);
```

Comment: Just as a sanity check: what happens if you call CreateEvent() with parameter bManualReset = false, then skip all calls to the ResetEvent() function? If it is false, WaitFor functions will automatically clear the event.

Comment: With - 936fps, W/O - 716. What's the problem, really?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz this is just a test set of opengl calls, when I get everything setup proper, there will be much more opengl calls and I think it will matter more then


Lundin When I do that I get around the same FPS

Comment: Seems like your threads are just taking turns. For proper producer/consumer, wait for *enough open space in the queue*, not for *queue completely empty again*.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you expect this to be faster?

Only one thread is ever doing anything, you create the commands in one thread and the signal the other and wait for it to finish which will take just as long as just doing it in the first thread, only with more overhead.

TO take advantage of multithreading you need to ensure that both threads are doing something at the same time.

Comment: So instead of making the main thread wait for the render thread to finish I should throw away commands sent from the main thread and allow it to do other things until the render thread is finished?

Comment: Build up the rending list and send it to the render thread like you've done, but then create a NEW rending buffer and start filling that while the rendering thread is processing the first one so they can overlap. Obviously this makes synchronisation more complex...

Comment: I have a few questions:

Is it ideal to have 2 command queues, or should I have more?
How should I handle the main thread being much faster than the rendering thread? Is it okay for it to skip rendering one of the command queues if it's full and the render thread hasn't finsihed yet?

Comment: Too hard to answer that here really as it's all major design stuff. I would wait for the render thread _after_ you've generated the new command list so you don't get ahead but can still overlap a bit. Be aware that to some degree rendering APIs already do this internally so you may not gain as much as you expect from doing this. Also, you need to be careful about using opengl commands from two threads, I'm not sure what is legal as mostly I know direct3d where there are certain restrictions.

Comment: OpenGL is inherently single-threaded (context must be active in exactly one thread at a time). Therefore the only _sensible_ way of using OpenGL with multithreading to get a little extra performance is to use a second/third thread to fill a mapped buffer. Everything else only adds context switching overhead. Irrespective of that, it makes sense to handle window messages in another thread, if you do a continuous animation (not for performance, but because otherwise the animation stops when the user moves/resizes the window).

Comment: @Damon One can set separate context for each thread and do a parallel rendering sharing resources between the contexts.

Comment: @MichaelIV: No, you cannot. You can set up two contexts (shared or not, doesn't matter) and render two different, unrelated things, but that is not helpful. If using shared contexts, you can further use one context to update textures and buffers, but you gain no extra performance over the solution above because the GL will synchronize to the best of its ability (in fact, on some drivers this yields significantly inferior performance, and you may get unexpected results in some conditions). You can _not_ "parallel render".

Comment: @Damon True.I was actually speaking about parallel renderings on completely separate contexts.

Comment: What I've done when playing with this is have three threads Thread 1) Works out which objects to draw and pushes which objects to draw into a queue for Thread 2) which works out how to draw them and pushes a list of drawing commands which contain (render states, texture index, vb index etc) to a queue which thread 3) reads and issues the appropriate opengl commands, It means that thread 3 basically does no work other than issuing drawing API commands so should be able to keep the device 100% busy...

Answer (score 0):

I am no opengl expert, but in general it is important to realize that threads are actually not used to speed things up, they are to guarantee that some subsystem is responsive *at the cost of overall speed*. That is one might keep a gui thread and a networking thread to ensure that the gui and networking are responsive. That is actually done at a performance *cost* to the main thread. The CPU is going to give 1/3 of its time to the main thread, 1/3 of its time to the networking thread and 1/3 of its time to the gui thread, even if there are no gui events to handle and nothing going in or out of the network. Thus whatever the main thread is doing gets only 1/3 of the CPU time that it would in a non-multithreaded situation. The upside is that if a lot of data starts arriving over the network, there is always CPU time reserved to handle it (which can be bad if there isn't as the networking buffer can be filled and then additional data starts being dropped or overwritten). The possible exception is that if multiple threads are running on different cores. However, even then be careful, cores can share the same caches, so if two cores are invalidating each other caches, performance could drop dramatically, not improve. If the cores share some resource to move data to and from the GPU or has some other shared limiting resource, this again could possibly cause performance losses, not gains.

In short, threading on a single CPU system is always about responsiveness of a subsystem, not performance. There are possible perfomance gains when different threads run on multiple cores (which windows doesn't seem to usually do by default, but it can be forced). However there are potential issues with doing this when those cores share some resource that could potentially hurt, not help, performance, e.g. shared cache space or some shared GPU related resource in your context.